# Confused about pointers and passing them as arguments

Tags: c

I'm trying to create an array of arbitrary size, and for some reason, this code here works:

```
int rand_tab(unsigned int n, int min, int max, int** dest){
    if(!(*dest = malloc(sizeof(int)*n))) return 0;
    return 1;
}
```

with the random number generation in main:

```
int* tab;
if(!(rand_tab(taille, min, max, &tab))) return -1;
for(i=0; i<taille; i++) tab[i] = random(min, max);
```

but this crashes(though it compiles just fine):

```
int rand_tab(unsigned int n, int min, int max, int** dest){
    if(!(*dest = malloc(sizeof(int)*n))) return 0;
    for(i=0; i<n; i++) *dest[i] = random(min, max);
    return 1;
}
```

since I pass `&tab` to the function, `dest` now points to `tab`, meaning `*dest[i]` should be equivalent to writing `tab[i]` in main.

If I replace `*dest[i]` by `*(*dest+i)`it works though. What is happening here?

Comment: Precedence: `*` has lower precedence than `[]`.  Use `(*dest)[i]` in the function.

Comment: This has to be a duplicate, probably many times over.  The difficulty, as ever, is finding the duplicate.  It's far harder to find the duplicate than to answer the question.

Comment: Indeed, thank you for your help, I feel quite silly now. As for finding the duplicate, if I could've found it in the first place I wouldn't have needed to ask this question. Cheers!

Comment: The jibe about finding the duplicate is aimed at the world in general and to some extent at the SO team — it was not aimed at you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the following expression

```
*dest[i] = random(min, max)
```

needs parentheses around `*dest`:

```
(*dest)[i] = random(min, max)
```

Since square brackets `[]` operator has higher precedence than dereference operator `*`, order needs to be forced with parentheses to match the one that you need. Otherwise, C interprets `dest` as an array of pointers, reads a value from `dest+1` (undefined behavior) and tries to dereference it (undefined behavior again).